# python requests with cookielib equivalent to wget with --load-cookies

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, wget

I'm trying to authenticate on a website using python `requests`.

I use a Chrome extension named [cookie.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookiestxt/njabckikapfpffapmjgojcnbfjonfjfg) to save the cookies file from a Chrome session on the website I want to authenticate on.

When I use following wget command

```
wget -O hp.html -x --load-cookies cookies.txt http://www.thewebsite.com
```

It works: I get the webpage with authenticated content

But when I try to do the same thing using Python Requests package with

```py
import cookielib
import requests

cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar('cookies.txt')
cj.load()

url = 'http://www.thewebsite.com'
r = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
```

I get an error 400 status

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?